# Upload de arquivo retornando "Missing a temporary folder"

Tags: php, linux

Tenho meu site hospedado na GoDaddy e nesse site tenho uma parte para uploads, isso funcionava bem até dias atrás, agora começou retornar o erro **6 - Missing a temporary folder** para qualquer arquivo que eu tente subir, tentei diversas formas de resolver, alterando o php.ini e mesmo assim nada.

No meu arquivo PHP se eu usar o comando `file_exists(sys_get_temp_dir());` me retorna true, então a pasta está lá.

Se eu usar o comando `is_writable(sys_get_temp_dir());` me retorna false, talvez ai esteja o problema, porém a pasta **/tmp** do meu servidor (que é a que está configurada, a padrão) está com a permissão `drwxrwxrwt.`.

Se alguem puder me ajudar nesse problema, já que segui vários tutoriais e nada da solução.

Comment: O que aparece quando você roda isso: `$ ls -l /tmp`

Comment: Me da uma lista  de arquivos e pastas, como é bastante coisa vou atualizar minha pergunta com os dados que aparecem lá.

Comment: Amigo acho que você colocou uma barra no final do comando que eu falei, e isso fez retornar a lista do que tem dentro da pasta `/tmp`.  O comando `$ ls -l /tmp` era pra retornar algo mais ou mesmo assim: `lrwxrwxrwx@ 1 root  admin  11 Nov 18 23:55 /tmp -> private/tmp`

Comment: Se as permissões da pasta não estiverem `lrwxrwxrwx` o problema deve ser só isso, se já estiver assim então verifica no seu `php.ini` se ele realmente está usando o diretório `/tmp`.

Comment: @KayoBruno com o comando que me disse ele mostra o que tem dentro da pasta, seu eu der um `ls -l /` ele me retorna os dados dessa pasta /tmp e o retorno é `drwxrwxrwt.  14 root root  4096 Mar 12 02:23 tmp`

Comment: Opa @GabrielQueirozSchicora veja se isso te ajuda https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343809/php-is-writable-function-always-returns-false-for-a-writable-directory

Comment: @ThiagoCosta Quando executei o camando `sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /tmp` me deu vários avisos falando `chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file ‘NOME_DO_ARQUIVO’` onde NOME_DO_ARQUIVO é o nome dos arquivos intenos da pasta `/tmp` e por final a mensagem `chcon: failed to change context of ‘/tmp’ to ‘system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0’: Read-only file system`.

Comment: Eu tinha visto várias pessoas falando para dar um `chmod 777 /tmp` e resolveria, mas me da erro também por ser um `Read-only file system`, então vi gente falando para fazer o mount e remount (Não conheço bem esses comandos do linux) mas também me da erro que não pode executar o remount nessa pasta.

Comment: Na segunda resposta do link que me mandou, diz para usar o 'sestatus' para ver o status do SELinux (Também não conheco para que serve) mas ele está como desativado, isso deveria estar ativado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, o problema foi resolvido e é mais estraho que eu imaginava, vou deixar a resposta aqui para servir de ajuda caso alguem tenha o mesmo problema.

Foi necessário executar o comando `chmod 777 /tmp`, porém esse comando não podia ser executado já que dava erro que a pasta era somente leitura (Ready-Only file system). Para resolver isso era necessário fazer o mount e remount mas também não conseguia pois não deixava eu fazer o remount da pasta `/tmp`

Por outro motivo precisei reiniciar o servidor e magicamente o servidor deixou eu alterar as permições para 777 (de `drwxrwxrwt.` para `drwxrwxrwx.`). Com isso problema resolvido.

Agradeço a todos que tentaram ajudar.